# Откуда разница в высоте ссылки и вложенного в неё изображения?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть тег `<a>` и вложенное в него изображение `<img>`. А именно:

```
<a href="" class="header__logo">
  <img src="img/header/Header__logo.png" width="120px" height="37px" alt="">
</a>
```

При заданной высоте изображения в 37px высота ссылки становится равной 39px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При изменении высоты изображения на любое другое значение высота ссылки принимает значение на 2px больше.
Что это за магия такая? И как же избавиться от этих 2px?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing ?

Comment: Укажи для img display: block это избавляет от огромного количества такого рода проблем